# Pulse CMS - Recent posts - Show (100) characters

Tags: php, content-management-system, pulse

Had a client come to me about there site and they are using Pulse CMS, they wanted to show the recent posts on the homepage, easy... but I can't see how to show a small bit of the post. My php knowledge is limited.

From this:

Post Title
01/02/03

See All

---

To this:

Post Title
01/02/03

New dawn new day, recent post content...

See All

---

Here's the code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
include_once("config.php"); 
include_once("path.php");
include_once("helpers/blog_lib.php");
include_once("helpers/functions.php");

if($pulse_lang == 0){
include_once("lang.php");}  
else
if($pulse_lang == 1){
include_once("lang_de.php");}

$blog_file = new read_File("blog");$amount = $blog_file->countLines();
$lines = $blog_file->getLines();$amount_view = 1 ;

echo "<div class=\"span3 latest-post-1\">\n\n";

for ($n=$amount-1  ;  $n>=($amount - $amount_view)  ;  $n-- ) { 
$blog = explode("|", $lines[$n]);

if (isset($blog[0]) & $blog[0] != '') {

    $date = explode( ' ' , $blog[2]);
    $date = $date[2] . ' ' . $date[1]  . ' ' . $date[3];

    include("clean_url.php");

    if($rewrite) {

        if ($blog_comments) {

            echo "<p><a href=\"/blog-". $blog[0]     ."-".cleanUrlname($blog[3])."\">" .$blog[3]. "</a> (" .$blog[1]. ")<br>";

        } else {

            echo "<p><a href=\"/blog-". $blog[0] ."-".cleanUrlname($blog[3])."\">" .$blog[3]. "</a><br>";
        }

    } else { 

        if ($blog_comments) {

            echo "<p><a href=\"". $blog_url ."?d=". $blog[0] ."\">"    .$blog[3]."</a> (" .$blog[1]. ")<br>";

        } else {

            echo "<p><a href=\"". $blog_url ."?d=". $blog[0] ."\">" .$blog[3]."</a><br>";

        }
    }

    if($date_format) {

        echo date("d.m.Y", strtotime($date))."</p>\n\n";

    } else {

        echo date("m-d-Y", strtotime($date))."</p>\n\n";
    } 
}
}

echo "<p class=\"all-posts\"><a href=\"". $blog_url ."\">$lang_blog_see_all</a></p>";
echo "\n\n</div>";
?>
```

It simply fetches the title and date the blog posts from a .txt file so surely someone can pull say "100" characters of the post through aswell.

***EDIT***

Here's the code for the read file:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

(function() {
var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async =     true;
po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
})();  
</script>

<?php
error_reporting(0);
include_once("config.php"); 
include_once("path.php");
if($pulse_lang == 0){ include_once("lang.php");} elseif($pulse_lang == 1){    include_once("lang_de.php");}
include_once("helpers/blog_lib.php");
include_once("helpers/functions.php");


if(!isset($_POST["question"])){ $question = array_rand($questions, 1); $answer =     strtolower($questions[$question]); }

?>
<link rel="alternate" title="RSS" href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];     ?>/<?php echo $pulse_dir; ?>/rss.php" type="application/rss+xml" >
<link href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>/<?php echo $pulse_dir; ?>/css/blog.css" rel="stylesheet" >
<div class="blog-wrap">
<?php

$blog_file_1 = new read_File("blog");
$amount = $blog_file_1->countLines();
$lines = $blog_file_1->getLines();

//id given - validating new comment and displaying a sepcific blog post
if(isset($_GET["d"]) && strlen($_GET["d"] > 0) && is_numeric($_GET["d"]) ) { $id_post = super_clean($_GET["d"]); 

// security
if(!empty($_POST["answers"]) 
    &&  $questions[stripslashes(html_entity_decode($_POST["question"]))] ==  strtolower(trim($_POST["answers"])) 
    &&  md5($questions[stripslashes(html_entity_decode($_POST["question"]))]) ==  $_POST["token"]) {
        $resp = 1;
        $question = array_rand($questions, 1);  
        $answer = strtolower($questions[$question]);
        } elseif (isset($_POST["answers"])) {
            $resp = 2;
            $question = array_rand($questions, 1);  
            $answer = strtolower($questions[$question]);    
        }

        if($blog_capcha == false){ $resp = 1;}


    if (strlen($_POST['comment'])> 1000){ $too_long = true; }   

//1.validate and save new comment -id and form
if(!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['mail']) && !empty($_POST['comment']) && empty($_POST['ph']) &&  $blog_comments && ($too_long != true) ) {

        //sanatizing content    
        $email = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['mail'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
        $name = strip_tags(trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])));        
        $comment = strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['comment']),'<p><br><a>');
        $comment = htmlspecialchars($comment, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        $x=0;// for mail

        if(preg_match("/@/", $_POST['mail'])) {

            if($resp == 1) {
                $x=1;

                $comment = str_replace("\n", "<br />", $comment);
                $comment = str_replace("\r", "", $comment);
                $comment = str_replace("|", "&brvbar;", $comment);
                $postdate = date('D, d M Y H:i:s O');
                $blog = $id_post."|".$postdate."|".$name."|".$email."|".$comment."\n";                  

                    //check if comment already exists
                        $comment_saved = 0; 

                        $comment_file_1 = new read_File("comment");
                        $amount_c = $comment_file_1->countLines();
                        $lines_c = $comment_file_1->getLines();

                        for($i=0; $i < $amount_c; $i++) { 
                            $comments = explode("|", $lines_c[$i]);
                            if($comments[0] == $id_post) {                  
                                if(($comments[0] == $id_post) && ($comments[2] == $name) && ($comments[3] == $email) && ($comments[4] == $comment)){
                                    $comment_saved = 1;
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                //validated new comment; save it
                if ($comment_saved == 0){           

                    $add = new add_Content("comment", $blog);
                    echo $add->appendData();

                    //update Number of comments  
                    for($i=0; $i < $amount; $i++) { 
                        $blogg = explode("|", $lines[$i]);

                        if($blogg[0] == $id_post){        
                            $blogg[1]++;
                            $new_data .=  $blogg[0]. "|" . $blogg[1] ."|".$blogg[2]."|".$blogg[3]."|".$blogg[4]."|".$blogg[5]."\n";                 
                            } elseif($blogg[0] != "") {
                                $new_data .=  $blogg[0]. "|" . $blogg[1] ."|".$blogg[2]."|".$blogg[3]."|".$blogg[4]."|".$blogg[5]."\n";
                                }
                        }
                        $write = new add_Content("blog", $new_data);
                        echo $write->writeData();

                    //send mail
                    if($x===1){             
                        for($i=0; $i < $amount; $i++) { 
                            $b = explode("|", $lines[$i]);
                            if($b[0] == $id_post){ 
                                $title = $b[3];
                             }
                         }  


                         $comment_dec = trim(strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['comment'])));
                         $sender_Name = "PulseCMS"; 
                         $sender_email = $email_contact;
                         $recipient = $email_contact;
                         $mail_body = $lang_blog_notify."\n\n";
                         $mail_body .= $lang_blog_title.": ".$title."\n\n";
                         $mail_body .= $lang_blog_name.": ".$name."\n\n";
                         $mail_body .= $lang_blog_comment.": ".$comment_dec."\n\n";         
                         $subject = $lang_blog_subject;
                         $header = "From: ". $sender_Name . " <" . $sender_email . ">\r\n";
                         mail($recipient, $subject, $mail_body, $header);

                      }//end mail
                } //end save new comment

                unset($email);
                unset($name);
                unset($comment);
                unset($_POST['submit']);
                unset($comment_file_1);

                $_POST['name'] = '';
                $_POST['mail'] = '';
                $_POST['comment'] = '';

        } // end resp                       
} else { $error = 1;}//end pregmatch email                      
 } else //end validating and saving new comment


            //2.show specific blog post and comments - id
            $no_posts_found=0;

            $blog_file_1 = new read_File("blog");
            $amount = $blog_file_1->countLines();
            $lines = $blog_file_1->getLines();
            for($i=0; $i < $amount; $i++) { 
                $blog = explode("|", $lines[$i]);

                if($blog[0] == $id_post) {
                    $no_posts_found++;
                    $date = explode( ' ' , $blog[2]);
                    $date = $date[2] . ' ' . $date[1]  . ' ' . $date[3];
                    $title = cleanUrlname($blog[3]);

                    echo "<h2 class=\"blog-title\">" .$blog[3]."</h2>\n";

                    if($date_format) { echo "<div class=\"blog-date\">" . date("d-m-Y", strtotime($date))."</div>\n"; } 
                        else { echo "<div class=\"blog-date\">" . date("m-d-Y", strtotime($date))."</div>\n"; }
                            echo "<div class=\"blog-content\">" . str_replace("##more##", "", $blog[4]) ."</div>\n\n";
                            break;
                }
             } if($no_posts_found == 0){
                        echo "404 ~does not~ exist.";
                        header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 404 Not Found');
                        die();
                    }

                echo "<script>document.title = \"$blog[3]\";</script>\n";

                ?>  
                <div        class="share-buttons    ">
                <div        style='float:left;pa    dding-right:15px'>
                <div        class="g-plusone" da    ta-size="medium" data-annotation="none"></div></div >   
                <div        style='float:left;pa    dding-right:15px'>
                <a a    l   ign="bottom" href="h    ttps://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-butt o   n" data-count="none"    >Tweet</a>
                <scr    i   pt src="//platform.t    witter.com/widgets.js"></script></div>
                <div        style='float:left;'>    
                <fb:    l   ike colorscheme='light' expr:hr ef='data:post.url' font='' data-    widt    h   ="300" layout='button_count' se nd='false' show_faces='false'/></div><  /div    >   
                        <?ph    p   

                        // show comments                        
                        if($blog_comments) {    

                    echo     "<div class=\"comments\" id=\"c    omments\">";

                        $comment    _file_2 = new re    ad_File(    "comment");
                        $amount_    c_2 = $comment_f    ile_2->c    ountLines();
                        $lines_c    _2 = $comment_fi    le_2->ge    tLines();

                        for($i=0    ; $i < $amount_c_2; $i++    ) { 
                                    $comments = explode("|",     $lines_c_2[$i]);
                            if($    comments[0] == $id_post)     {

                                $date = explode( ' ' , $    comments[1]);
                                $date = $date[2] . ' ' .     $date[1]  . ' ' . $date[3];

                                echo "<div class=\"comme    nt-line\">\n";

                            if($date_format)    { echo  "<div class=\"comment-date\">". date("d-m-Y", strtotime(    $date)) ."</div>\n"; } 
                                else { echo "   <div cl ass=\"comment-date\">". date("m-d-Y", strtotime($da te))."< /div>\n"; } 
                                    echo "<di   v class =\"comment-name\">". $comments[2]."</div>\n";   
                                    echo "</div>\n";    
                                    echo "<div class=\"blog-comment\">" .$comment   s[4]."< /div>\n\n"; 
                                }   
                            }   


    //display comment form only if s    et to enable        
    for($i=0; $i < $amount; $i++) {     
        $blog = explode("|", $lines[$i]);   

if( ($blog[0] == $id_post) && ($blog[5] == 1) ){ echo "<p class=\"comments-off\">   $lang_blog_off_comments</p>"; }                 

    if( ($blog[0] ==     $id_post) && ($blog[5] != 1) ){                        


    ?>  
    <form class="comment-form" action="<?php if($rewrite) {e    cho "blog-$id_post-".cleanU rlname( $blog[3]);} else {echo "?d=$id_post";}?>" method="post">    
    <?php $_POST = array_map('trim', $_POST);?> 

        <p class="add"><b><?php echo $lang_blog_add_comment;?></b></p>  

    <p><label class="comment-label"><?php echo $lang_blog_label_name;   
                if(isset($_POST['submit']) && empty($_POST['name'])) { echo "<span  style=\"color:red\">  - $lang_blog_error_name</span>";}?></label><br    />  
        <input type="text" name="name" size="45" value="<?php echo strip_tags(trim(strips   lashes  ($_POST['name']))); ?>" /></p>  

        <p><label cla   ss="comment-label"><?php echo $lang_blog_label_email;   
                    i   f((isset($_POST['submit']) && empty($_POST['mail']))|| $error==1) {e    cho "<  s   pan style=\"color:red\"> - $lang_blog_error_email</span>";}?></label    ><br /  >   
        <input size="45" type="text" name="mail" value="<?php echo strip_tags(trim(strips   lashes  ($_POST['mail']))); ?>" /></p>  

    <p><label class="comment-label"><?php echo $la  ng_blog_label_comment;  
                if(isset($_POST['submit']) && empt  y($_POST['comment'])){ ec   ho "<span   style=\"color:red\">  - $lang_blog  _error_comment</span>";}    
                    if ($too_long == true){echo "<span   style=\"color:red\">  -Your comment    is  too long</span>";}?></label><br />  
        <textarea name="comment" cols="60" rows="7"><?php echo strip_tags(trim(stripslashes (   $_POST['comment']))); ?></textarea></p> 

        <p><input id="ph" size="45" type="text" name="ph" value="<?php echo strip_tags(trim (   stripslashes($_POST['ph']))); ?>" /></p>    


 <?php if( ($blog_capcha == true) || (!isset($blo   g_capcha))  ){ ?>   
    <p><label class="comment-label"><?php ec    ho $question; if ($resp == 2) {e    cho "<span  style=\"color:red\">  - $lang_blog_error    _captcha</span>";}?> </label><br     />     
            <input type="hidden" name="token" value=    "<?php echo md5($answer); ?>" />    
            <input type="hidden" name="question" val    ue="<?php echo htmlentities($question); ?>" /   >
            <input type="text" name="answers" /></p>    
<?php }     ?>          



    <p><button class="btn" type="submit" name ="submit"><?php echo $lang_blog_submit; ?><   /button></p>    

        </form> 
        <?php       
                        }//blogcomm ents enables        
        }// end comment and ip-post 
                        echo '</div>';              

    }}//end display commment form if enabled    


//s earch           
els e if(isset($_GET['search']) && strlen($_GET['search'])>0  && strlen($_GET['search'])<50     ) { 
                    include("blog_search.php"); 

            }   

//blog default              
else {  

?><a class="search-icon" href="#search">    
<img src="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>/
     <?php echo $pulse_dir;?><?php  

$result_per_page = $per_page ;  
$total_pages = ceil($amount/$result_per_page);  

    $cur_page = $_GET[page] ? $_GET[page] : 1;  

    $start = $amount - (($cur_page-1) * $result_per_page);  
    $end = $amount - (($cur_page) * $result_per_page);  

for     ($n=$start-1  ;  $n>=$end  ;  $n-- ) {  
        $blog = explode("|", $lines[$n]);   

    if (    isset($blog[0]) & $blog[0] != '') { 

            $date = explode( ' ' , $blog[2]);   
            $date = $date[2] . ' ' . $date[1]  . ' ' . $date[3];    

        echo "<div class=\"entry\">\n"; 
        if($rewrite) { echo "<h2 class=\"blog-title\"><a href=\ "blog-". $blog[0] ."-". cleanUrlname($blog[3])."\">" .$blog[3]."</a></h2>\n"; } 
             else {  echo "<h2 class=\"blog-title\"><a href=\"?d=". $blog[0] ."\">" .$blog[ 3]."</a></h2>\n"; }

            if($date_format)     { echo "<div class=\"blog-date\">" . date("d-m-Y", strtotime($date ))."</div>\n";}     
                 else { echo "<div class=\"blog-date\">" . date("m-d-Y", strtotime($d   ate))."<    /div>\n"; }     

            if(preg_match("/^(.*)##more##/U", $blog [4], $m)) { 
                    if($rewrite) { echo "<div class =\"blog-content\">" . $m[1] ." <a   href=\"blog-". $blog[0] ."-".cl eanUrlname($blog[3])."\" class=\"read-more\"    >$lang_blog_more</a></div>\n";} 
                         else { echo "<div class=\"blog-content\">" . $m[1] ." <a href=\"?d=".  $blog[0] ."\" class=\"read-more\">$lang_blog_more</a></div>\n";}
                } else { echo "<div class=\"blog-content\">" . $blog[4] ."</div>\n"; }

            if($blog_commen ts)  {  
                if($blog[1] ) { 
                    if($rew rite) { echo  "<div class=\"num_    comments\"><a href=\"   blog-". $blog[0 ] ."-". cleanUrlname($blog[3])."#comment    s\">(". $blog[1] .")    $lang_b log_num_comment</a></div>\n\n";}    
                      else  {echo  "<div class=\"num_comments\"><a href=\"?d=". $blog[0] .  "#com   ments\">(". $blog[1] .") $lang_blog_num_comment</a></div>\n"; }
                   } else { 
                        if($rewrite)    { ec    ho "<div class=\"num_comments\"><a href=\"blog-".   $blog[0] ."-"   .cle    anUrlname($blog[3])."#comments\">$lang_blog_no_comment  </a></div>\n\   n";}    
                             else { e   cho "<div class=\"num_comments\"><a href=\"?d=". $blog[0]   ."#comme    nts\">$lang_blog_no_comment</a></div>"; }   
                         }              
            }   
            ec  ho "</div>  \n\n";  
        }// en  d if blog0  
        else {   continue; }    
    }//end for  
    echo '<div class="blog-pagination   ">';
        if ($cur_page<$total_pages) {   
            if($rewrite) {  echo "<a href=\"". $prefix ."blog-p age-" . ($cur_page+1) . "\">" .     $lang_blog_older . "</a>" . "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";}  
                else { echo "<a href=\"?page=" . ($cur_page+1) . "\">" . $lang_blog_older . "<  /a>" . "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";}       
        }   
        if ($cur_page>1) {          
            if($rewrite) { echo  "<a href   =\"". $prefix ."blog-page-" . ($cur_page-1) . "\">" .   $lang_blog_newer . "</a>"; }    
                else {  echo "<a href=\"?page=" . ($cur_page-1) . "\">" . $lang_blog_newer . "< /a>" . "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"; }  
         }

echo '</div>';

?>  
<form id="searc h" name="blog_search" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SEL F']); ?>    " method="get"> 
    <input id="searchword" name="search" type="text" maxlength="50" value="<?php echo   super_clean($_GET['search']); ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $lang_blog_search; ?>">
</form>
<?php

}//default: blog post collection

echo '</div>';

?>
```

*** RE-EDITED ***

```
<?php

class read_File{

function __construct($name){        
    $this->name = $name;    

    if($this->name == "blog"){$this->name = ROOTPATH . "/data/blog/blogfile.txt";}
    else if($this->name == "comment"){$this->name = ROOTPATH . "/data/blog/comments.txt";}
    else { echo $lang_blog_error_reading;}          
 }  

function getData(){
    $open = fopen($this->name , "r");
    $data = @fread($open, filesize($this->name));
    fclose($open);      
    return $data;       
}   

function getLines(){                
    $lines = explode("\n", $this->getData());
    return $lines;
}

function countLines(){  
    $amount_of_lines = count($this->getLines());
    return $amount_of_lines-1;      
}   


}//end class

class add_Content{

    function __construct($name,$data){      
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->data = $data;    

    if($this->name == "blog"){$this->name = ROOTPATH . "/data/blog/blogfile.txt";}
    else if($this->name == "comment"){$this->name = ROOTPATH . "/data/blog/comments.txt";}
    else { echo $lang_blog_error_reading;}
    }

    function appendData(){
        $open = fopen($this->name, "a");
        fwrite($open, $this->data);
        fclose($open);
    }

    function writeData(){           
        $open = fopen($this->name, "w");
        fwrite($open, $this->data);
        fclose($open);          
    }           
}//end class

//sanatize input
function super_clean($text){    
$text = trim(stripslashes(strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'))));   
return $text;
}           
?>
```

- EDIT *

var_dump out:

```
array(6) { [0]=> string(1) "5" [1]=> string(1) "0" [2]=> string(31) "Fri, 11 Oct 2013     13:04:17 +0200" [3]=> string(7) "Subject" [4]=> string(54) "

This is a sample blog post for Pulse CMS Pro.
" [5]=> string(1) "0" }
```

blogfile lines:

```
4|0|Fri, 11 Oct 2013 12:57:09 +0200|hey this works|<p>  Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>|0
5|0|Fri, 11 Oct 2013 13:04:17 +0200|Subject|<p>  This is a sample blog post for Pulse CMS Pro.</p>|0
```

Comment: You might want to post the code for `read_File()`, as that seems to be the code that's fetching the post data.

Comment: Sorry about that, Edited the original post.

Comment: There's still no definition for the `read_file` class.

Comment: Sorry I thought read_File("blog"); ment blog.php file. Like I say my php is rubbish, What am looking for to post,

Comment: Somewhere in your code, there's a file that includes `class read_file {` - that's the definition for the class that's reading the files.

Comment: Just thought about it and brain kicked in lol, having a very bad day.

Comment: Nothing more coffee won't fix ;)

Comment: lol true, on about the tenth cup.

Comment: Dear me, that's messy code. It's using text files to store the details of the posts, and I'm fairly sure that you're pulling the content already, but I can't figure out which field it is. So as a WAG - try `echo substr($blog[1], 0, 100)`

Comment: where do i chuck that line of code mate

Comment: Just above the line that starts `echo "<p class=\"all-posts\">` - it's not going to be formatted, but that's easy to add in.

Comment: right, inserted echo substr($blog[1], 0, 100);

Comment: comes back showing a 0 where content would be

Comment: Pah. Alright; just comment out that line, as we'll be needing it again shortly, and replace it with a `var_dump($blog)` - that will print out the whole `$blog` array so we can figure out what we should be using.

Comment: yep, showing array(6) { [0]=> string(1) "5" [1]=> string(1) "0" [2]=> string(31) "Fri, 11 Oct 2013 13:04:17 +0200" [3]=> string(7) "Subject" [4]=> string(196) " etc.

Comment: Ah. I expect we need to use `[5]` instead of `[1]`, then.

Comment: echo substr($blog[5], 0, 100); try that shows 0 again

Comment: Alright. Can you update your question with the output when you have the `var_dump` in the code?

Comment: Do you mean the html output?

Comment: Just the output of the var_dump - the `array(6) { [0]=> string(1) "5"`. Basically, I need to see the fields in each blog post. Though I guess you could also post a couple of lines of `blogfile.txt`, too.

Comment: done mate, re edited to show var dump and blogfile

Comment: Ah-ha! It's `[4]`. Since it's also including HTML, you might need to use: `echo substr(strip_tags($blog[4]), 0, 100)`

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for that pal and for putting up with a tired idiot lol.

Comment: No problem; glad to have helped.